# Pausing main thread until Async Task is complete

Tags: java, android

I have an Async Task that creates a database that will be used immediately after (so the task must finish before continuing). I also can't use postExecute because the database will not be created every single time, and using the get() method does not seem to be working.

Here is the code that executes the Async Task.

```
try {
    DatabaseCreator create = new DatabaseCreator();
    create.execute("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=xml&api_key="+foodDataKey + "&fg=0900&max=360",
                   "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=xml&api_key="+foodDataKey + "&fg=1100&max=836",
                   "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=xml&api_key="+foodDataKey + "&fg=0100&max=283").get();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Here is the Async Task itself.

```
class DatabaseCreator extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> products = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                URL connect = new URL(params[i]);
                URLConnection foodConnect = connect.openConnection();
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(foodConnect.getInputStream()));
                String input;
                ArrayList<String> currentGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (i ==  0) {
                    currentGroup.add("Fruits");
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    currentGroup.add("Vegetables");
                } else {
                    currentGroup.add("Dairy");
                }
                while ((input = read.readLine()) != null){
                    if (input.contains("<name>")) {
                        if (input.trim().length() < 8) {
                            String temp = read.readLine().trim();
                            temp = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf(","));
                            if (currentGroup.contains(temp) == false) {
                                currentGroup.add(temp);
                            }
                        } else {
                            String temp = input.trim();
                            //Log.d("HOME", temp + " " + temp.indexOf("<name>"));
                            temp = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("<name>") + 6, temp.indexOf("</name>"));
                            if (temp.indexOf(",") == -1) {
                                if (currentGroup.contains(temp) == false) {
                                    currentGroup.add(temp);
                                }
                            } else {
                                temp = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf(","));
                                if (currentGroup.contains(temp) == false) {
                                    currentGroup.add(temp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                products.add(currentGroup);
            }
            return products;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> prods) {
        //Log.d("HOME", "HHIIHIH");
        for (int i = 0; i < prods.size(); i++) {
            //Log.d("HOME", prods.get(i)+"");
            database.add(prods.get(i));
        }
        //Log.d("HOMEEEE", database.size()+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont' you just show a loading screen?

Comment: There is another Async Task in my program that is also experiencing the same problem. I feel like it would be much easier to just figure this out rather than creating a bunch of loading screens

Comment: Load your remaining task in on post method.

Comment: @avi1234, point out that on which line you need to pause ?

Comment: I don't need the Async Task itself to pause; instead, I need the task to finish executing before moving out of the execution. For example, if I had a Log line after the create.execute, I want that Log line to print after a Log line in the Task itself.